# pandas timeseries identification values based on date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas 30min interval timeseries.
A small sample looks like:

```
2009-12-02 20:00:00    0.6
2009-12-02 20:30:00    0.7
2009-12-03 01:00:00    0.7
2009-12-03 02:30:00    0.7
2009-12-03 11:30:00    0.7
2009-12-03 12:00:00    1.4
2009-12-03 12:30:00    1.3
```

I must indentify starting , finished date (and store it) if the interval between 2 continues timestamp is more than 2 hours.
for example :

```
event 1 : 2009-12-02 20:00:00 -  2009-12-02 20:30:00 
event 2 : 2009-12-03 01:00:00 -  2009-12-03 02:30:00  
event 3 : 2009-12-03 11:30:00 -  2009-12-03 12:30:00
```

but i am a bit stuck here!!! Usually, if it was a DataFrame i would use something like :
`for index, row df.iterrows():`
     `#if timedelta > 2 hours etc`

Any suggestion how i could start?
Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Calculate the time difference between two rows.
2. Get a bool series by compare the difference with 2 hours.
3. cumsum() the bool series to get a series that can split the dateframe.
4. call groupby and apply to get the begin and end datetime for every group.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

data = r"""date,value
2009-12-02 20:00:00,0.6
2009-12-02 20:30:00,0.7
2009-12-03 01:00:00,0.7
2009-12-03 02:30:00,0.7
2009-12-03 11:30:00,0.7
2009-12-03 12:00:00,1.4
2009-12-03 12:30:00,1.3"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), parse_dates=[0])
diff = df.date - df.date.shift(1)

sections = (diff > np.timedelta64(2, "h")).astype(int).cumsum()

def f(s):
    return s.iloc[[0, -1]].reset_index(drop=True)

print df.date.groupby(sections).apply(f).unstack()
```

output:

```
                   0                   1
0 2009-12-02 20:00:00 2009-12-02 20:30:00
1 2009-12-03 01:00:00 2009-12-03 02:30:00
2 2009-12-03 11:30:00 2009-12-03 12:30:00
```

Comment: Hyry,  absolutely pandaphonic way :). Ty

Comment: it would be useful to have a little more explanation as to exactly what's happening here. I have a similar problem and I'd like to be able to construct a solution similar to this one, but this code is so 'pandaphonic' as to look more like R than python. :p

Answer (score 0):

t.txt has the log data

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = d2 = d3 = None
for line in open('t.txt'):
    d3 = datetime.strptime(line[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if d1 is None:
        d1 = d2 = d3
    elif (d3 - d2).seconds >= 2 * 3600:
        print d1, d2
        d1 = d2 = d3
    else:
        d2 = d3
print d1, d2
```